# Spring Cloud Sleuth different trace-ID integrate with Kafka

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

I'm using Kafka for Asyng calls between microservices, and i'm using Spring Sleuth for logging. The logging is ok, but when there is a message from Microservice1 to Microservice2, the logging's messages have  different Trace-ID.  Don't they have to have the same trace-Id but a different SpanId? is there any special configuration?

Comment: Message headers by default will not be transported by Kafka binder, you have to set it via `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headers` manually as described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_kafka_binder_properties). And then check if those tracing related headers been sent properly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your snwer @tan9 ! :D.
I found this code from a yaml file:
spring:

  cloud:
    stream:

      kafka:
        binder:
           headers:
             - X-B3-TraceId
             - X-B3-SpanId
             - X-B3-Sampled
             - X-B3-ParentSpanId
             - X-Span-Name
             - X-Process-Id
    
Do you know how put in an application.properties file?

Comment: `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headers[0]=X-B3-TraceId`
`spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headers[1]=X-B3-SpanId`...
Or use `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headers=X-B3-SpanId,X-B3-SpanId,...`

Comment: Thank you, thank you very much @tan9! :D

Comment: I arranged above comment as a formal Answer below for other to reference easier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Message headers by default will not be transported by Spring Cloud Kafka binder, you have to set it via `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headers` manually as described in the [Spring Cloud Stream Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_kafka_binder_properties). And then check if those tracing related headers been sent properly.

You can set Zipkin headers as following in your application.yml:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          headers:
            - X-B3-TraceId
            - X-B3-SpanId
            - X-B3-Sampled
            - X-B3-ParentSpanId
            - X-Span-Name
            - X-Span-Export
```

Or in your application.properties:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headers[0]=X-B3-TraceId
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headers[1]=X-B3-SpanId
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headers[2]=B3-Sampled
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headers[3]=X-B3-ParentSpanId
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headers[4]=X-Span-Name
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headers[5]=X-Span-Export
```

Or in a comma-separated list:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headers=X-B3-TraceId,X-B3-SpanId,B3-Sampled,\
    X-B3-ParentSpanId,X-Span-Name,X-Span-Export
```