# Need to create a wrapper class that can assign uuid to the incoming kafka messages for tracing in graylog

Tags: spring-boot, session, logging, apache-kafka, uuid

There is a new requirement in our existing application like, attaching a uuid to all the incoming messages to kafkalistner in the request scope.we basically already have our own method of structuring the logs, all we need at this point is to have a scoped uuid that we can easily trace the messages using the uuid in graylog.

I am a beginner in apache kafka. so any working example with clear explanation of the code should be very helpful

Comment: Are you aware that [Spring Cloud Sleuth integrates with Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40923367/spring-cloud-sleuth-different-trace-id-integrate-with-kafka)?

Comment: Hi @ChinHuang, Thanks for your reply. Actually we are not using spring cloud or sleuth in our project. Here's something I just found that may be useful: 
https://medium.com/deskera-engineering/creating-user-session-for-kafka-consumer-using-custom-annotations-4625390c366a 

Basically we want a session for kafka transaction.Once we have a session, I believe we can attach a UUID to it , and retrieve it again when in to the log right? 

Does the approach in the above link would work for my case? Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your requirements fully - so I might be off in my suggestions....

My first assumption is that you have control over Kafka event producing - basically you (your app) are producing events using the Kafka Producer API.

My second assumption is that you want to trace your events by some session ( not sure what you mean by "request" scope here... request from where?) But I'm assuming that you know how to identify the session in some way... maybe you have a sessionID or a cookie available for that in your app...

If my above assumptions are on target - the easiest way to do what you want would be to just add two more fields to your events:

1. "sessionID" - with whatever value you use to identify the session/request
   and
2. and "uuid" - which would be a real global uuid, you can generate it using UUID class in Java in your producer app, if it is in Java, or an equivalent in other languages

And then you can easily groupBy/ filter by your sessionID field in Greylog or any other indexed log storage.

If you cannot add new fields to your events - for example you cannot easily modify event schema (although you should consider using a format that allows schema evolution then, like Avro, for example) - you could add those fields as Kafka event headers instead. I have never worked wiht Greylog but I would be surprised if it can't extract header values - any self-respecting log management platform should be able to do it :-)

Again, I might be off if I misunderstood your setup and requirements - in that case I apologize for the noise :-)